# Making a Google-Calendar-like dragging interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

When you use Google Calendar and want to make a new event, you can drag from the start time to the end time, and this creates the event in the desired range.

I want to implement the same functionality for my site using jQuery.

Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is to have time "slot" elements that each refer to a specific time (usually 15-minute intervals). Each slot element has an onmouseup and onmousedown handler. The mousedown handler, when triggered, stores the time referred to by that slot and updates a boolean variable that indicates whether dragging is occurring. When mouseup is triggered, the handler checks if dragging has started, and if so, decides that this is the ending slot. You now have a beginning and ending time, and you can take it from there to show some dialog that completes the rest of the booking.

**Demo:** http://www.dstrout.net/pub/appointment.htm
The demo also includes code to prevent text selection, since that is a "side-effect" of dragging. Check out the code to see how that works.

Comment: And if you want to display a preview during the drag operation, you can use the mousemove handler.

Comment: If you play around with the demo at all, you'll notice some shortcomings - you can drag from a later time to an earlier one and it will ask if you want to "set up an appointment from [later time] to [earlier time]". Also, there is no highlighting, which would doubtless be useful. These are left as an exercise for the user.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on the problem.  It steps by hours, but it would be easy enough to adapt to step by half-hour or fifteen-minute intervals.

The HTML:

```
<div id="hours">
    <div class="hour">8am</div>
    <div class="hour">9am</div>
    <div class="hour">10am</div>
    <div class="hour">11am</div>
    <div class="hour">...</div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var dragging;
var yOnMousedown;

$('.hour').mousedown( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass( 'hour-highlighted' );
    dragging = true;
    yOnMousedown = e.pageY;
} );​​​

$(document).mouseup( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dragging = false;
} );

$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    if( dragging ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hour').each( function() {
            var top = $(this).offset().top;
            var bottom = top + $(this).height();
            if( bottom > yOnMousedown && e.pageY > top )
                $(this).addClass( 'hour-highlighted' );
            else
                $(this).removeClass( 'hour-highlighted' );
        } );
    }
} );
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cv9LM/

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of mousedown, mousemove and mouseup

```
var dragging = false
$(someelement).mousedown(function(){
    dragging = true;
});

$(body).mousemove(function(){
    // In here you want to do all of the dragging functionality. Try using body,
    // window, document etc to see what works the best.
});

$(body).mouseup(function(){
    dragging = false;
    /* If you use an element here instead of body, document or window, when the
     user moves outside the element and lets go of the mousebutton, the dragging
     won't stop. */
});
```